# How to partially bind the html elements using the knockout

Tags: knockout.js, model-binding

```
        <html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="knockout-2.0.0.js"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" src="knockout.mapping.js"></script>   
</head>
  <div id="divFilter">
      Name <input type=text data-bind="value:NAME1"></input>
      <br>
      Address<input type=text data-bind="value:ADDRESS"></input>
      <br>
      DOB <input data-bind="value:DOB" id="DOB" name="DOB" type=text></input>
      <br>
      SSN <input data-bind="value:SSN" id="SSN" type=text></input>
  </div>
</html>
 <script>                
    var oVM_Summary=null;
    var VM_Summary= function(name1,address)
    {
         this.NAME1=ko.observable(name1);
         this.ADDRESS=ko.observable(address);             
    };
    oVM_Summary=new VM_Summary('Jon','123 addr');
    ko.applyBindings(oVM_Summary);
</script>
```

When the code gets executed then the DOB and SSN shows [object HTMLInputElement]
 Question:- How to avoid the binding for DOB and SSN.

```
    Thanks in advance...
```

Answer (score 2):

Update from your edits:

If your view model does not contain the `DOB` and `SSN` properties, then it will error out when trying to bind.  In your case, this is actually not happening, because in many browsers you can access elements by id off of the window object.  So, rather than not finding your properties it is finding `window.DOB` and `window.SSN`, which are the input elements.

If you change the names `DOB` and `SSN` in the ids, then you will start to see KO errors.  You should define them in your view model, even as empty.

Update based on your comment:
If you want to bind to multiple view models, then you will need to either do something like:

```
  <div id="divFilter">
      <div id="one">
         Name <input type="text" data-bind="value:NAME1" />
         <br/>
         Address<input type="text" data-bind="value:ADDRESS" />
      </div>
      <div id="two">
          DOB <input data-bind="value:DOB" id="DOB" name="DOB" type="text" />
          <br />
          SSN <input data-bind="value:SSN" id="SSN" type="text" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

applyBindings calls would look like:

```
ko.applyBindings(new VM_One(), document.getElementById("one"));
ko.applyBindings(new VM_Two(), document.getElementById("two"));
```

or you could do:

```
<div id="divFilter">
      <div data-bind="with: one">
         Name <input type="text" data-bind="value:NAME1" />
         <br/>
         Address<input type="text" data-bind="value:ADDRESS" />
      </div>
      <div data-bind="with: two">
          DOB <input data-bind="value:DOB" id="DOB" name="DOB" type="text" />
          <br />
          SSN <input data-bind="value:SSN" id="SSN" type="text" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS would look like:

```
var viewModel = {
    one: new VM_One(),
    two: new VM_Two()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my scenario I want to bind the DOB and SSN to other view model.

Comment: Updated for you to demonstrate two ways to bind multiple view models

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to `DOB` and `SSN`. They do not exist in the viewmodel. 
Add them and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want your user experience to be.  Do you want the DOB field to be avoided completely (i.e. not shown)?  Or do you want it to be shown, but with a default value?  Here is a way to do each of these:

You can avoid bindings altogether by using the 'if' binding.  The 'if' binding evaluates an expression and if true then processes the contained elements; otherwise ignores the contained elements.

The 'comment container' is very useful to host 'if' bindings, for example:

```
<!-- ko if:DOB -->
  DOB <input data-bind="value:DOB" id="DOB" name="DOB" type=text></input>
  <br>
<!-- /ko -->
```

On the other hand, if your desired experience is to keep the content, but replace null or undefined values with a default value (such as a blank), then you'll need to write some code somewhere to capture this business rule. One way is to use ko.computed(), documented on knockoutjs.com.

However my 2-cents is that ultimately easier to go ahead and in your constructor add the observable with a default value:

```
var VM_Summary= function(name1,address,dob,ssn)
{
    ...
    this.DOB=ko.observable(dob||'(none)');
    this.SSN=ko.observable(ssn||'(none)');
}
```

You would still call your constructor the same way:

```
oVM_Summary=new VM_Summary('Jon','123 addr');
```